# Lights flickering, socket only reading 80V, is this ground leakage?

Tags: electrical

I have a branch in my basement that powers three light sockets (only). It's old armored cable from the 1940s. Last month, all of the lights on the branch started flickering simultaneously (LED bulbs). I measured the voltage in the sockets and it was 80V, so something was amiss. I started at the fixture nearest the breaker panel and disconnected it, and measured the voltage on the incoming wires,120V. I then reconnected it and disconnected the 2nd fixture, and it was 120V. I then did the same to the third fixture and the voltage in was 120V, but when I connected it the voltage at all fixtures dropped to 80V.

I also had a $300 electrical bill last month, about 50% higher than usual.

Am I correct in diagnosing that there was a ground fault in the third fixture that's causing leakage current?

I replaced all the fixtures, been meaning to do that for a while, and the problem went away. I'm mostly asking because I'm trying to figure out why my electrical bill went up so much. I have gas heat, so it's not winter related.

Comment: I'm not an expert on US electrical systems, but in general, if there's current going somewhere it shouldn't be (and especially enough to show on a bill) that needs to be dealt with immediately.  If you can confidently locate it to a particular circuit, kill the circuit then call an electrician.  If not, kill all the power then call an electrician.  But I doubt this is what's costing $5/day, because that's the best part of a kW (at the price I pay) and if your wiring was getting that hot you'd have seen the flames on the first day

Comment: I'm guessing it was a loose connection somewhere. A ground fault would have burned something or tripped a breaker. Leaking wouldn't have doubled your electric bill. You have gas heat but you still have some electric blowers that circulate it and if they were running a lot it could cause the increase.

Comment: I would have said a loose connection but with everything just checked and the voltage diving with the last fixture and the high electrical bill there may be a short in the system, if possible I would disconnect that 3rd fixture and either replace the wiring and devices or get a FLIR camera with it connected and find the hot spot, really crazy things like a nail on one side of a cable then a few feet later a nail on the other side if a conductive path is there it turns into a heater, I have seen this with metal ducts and metal corner bead only a couple of times it happens and can be dangerous.